# datePicker minDate and maxDate do not work

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

The following code:

```
var minDate = moment(self.awardYears_Unformatted[a.charAt(6)].Begin).format("MM/DD/YYYY");
var maxDate = moment(self.awardYears_Unformatted[a.charAt(6)].End).format("MM/DD/YYYY");
tdForDatePicker.multiDatesPicker({
    numberOfMonths: [1, 3],
    dateFormat: "mm/dd/yyyy",
    minDate: minDate,
    maxDate: maxDate
});
tdForDatePicker2.multiDatesPicker({
    numberOfMonths: [1, 3],
    dateFormat: "mm/dd/yyyy",
    minDate: minDate,
    maxDate: maxDate
});
```

minDate is "10/21/2014"  and maxDate is "6/30/2015".  The outcome when I click on the input box to select a date is calendar months starting in 2021.  Thanks for a new suggestion.

Comment: I have tried spliting out minDate and maxdate using .split and rebuilding.  I have even tried raw dates and everything gives me months in 2021

Comment: minDate = 7/1/2015 maxDate = 6/30/2016  what shows in datepicker selection is a range from 8/10/2021 to 9/8/2021

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `dateFormat` is incorrectly specified. According to the [datepicker documentation](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/), one `y` stands for two year digits. Please try it this way:

```
dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy"
```

Comment: That was it.  Thank you.